# sed error invalid usage of line address 0

Tags: sed

I am using sed for :

```
RUN=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
INPUT_DIR=/path
OUTPUT_DIR=/path
INPUT_FILE=$(ls $INPUT_DIR/*.txt | sed -n ${RUN}p)
SAMPLE=$(basename "$INPUT_FILE" .txt)
echo "RUN #${RUN} with sample ${SAMPLE}"
```

But it gives error for line:

```
 INPUT_FILE=$(ls $INPUT_DIR/*.txt | sed -n ${RUN}p):
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: invalid usage of line address 0
```

It was working well before but gives an error now. I will appreciate any help to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: your `$RUN` is zero, do echo $RUN one  line above your `sed` command to validate.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: in never hurts to seperate `sed` syntax from shell syntax. maybe `sed -n "${RUN}p")`? Good luck.

Comment: What is the value of `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` and what are you trying to do (something like `find /path -name "*${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}*.txt -printf %f`) ?

Comment: COpy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about as a starting point. Also don't use all upper case for user-defined variable names to avoid clashing with builtin ones and obfuscating your code.